# Ambiguity in Huffman Tree

Tags: algorithm, huffman-code

I want to create a Huffman tree for four symbols a,b,c,d occurring with frequencies 5,4,3,2.

For simplicity, I'll ignore the symbol labels themselves and focus only on the frequency labels.

The first step, is to create 4 single vertex trees whose roots are labelled with the frequencies 5,4,3,2.

Next, merge the two single vertex trees whose roots are labelled 2,3 to get a three vertex tree whose root is labelled 3+2=5 and whose children are labelled 2,3.

The next step is to merge the tree labelled 4 with *one of the two other trees*, both of whose roots are labeled with frequency 5.

Which one to we choose?

The two choices lead to very different trees and Huffman codes. Specifically, one choice leads to a code with codeword lengths 1,2,3,3 and the other choice leads to codeword lengths 2,2,2,2.

In this particular case, the former code can't possibly be correct because its expected codeword length is longer ... this would violate the famous optimality of Huffman codes.

**What is a general prescription for constructing trees that always yields an optimal Huffman code?**

Comment: No, both codes are correct. You are calculating wrong. See my comment on your other question answering this.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Adler clarified this. For the record,

The *expected* codeword length for both codes proposed above are exactly 2 bits.

For the first code:
$5/14 * 1 + 4/14 * 2 + 3/14 * 3 + 2/14 * 3 = 2$

For the second code:
$5/14 * 2 + 4/14 * 2 + 3/14 * 2 + 2/14 * 2 = 2$

I guess that whichever way I break ties, the resulting code is optimal!

Thanks Mark!